# Android Viewpager does not refresh on scrolling Tabs

Tags: android, pagerslidingtabstrip

Hi,

I implemented sliding tab layout using Google's SlidingTabLayout. The position of tab changes on swiping View pager , but View pager does not refresh on scrolling Tabs like the way we see in contacts application where the user scrolls the tab and the View pager corresponding to particular tab also changes . Is there a way in which we can customize this  in SlidingTablayout ? can anyone help me in sorting out this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update content of fragment in onResume to ensure that content is updated.

Comment: I mean how to implement "onScrollChanged()"  method in SlidingTabLayout to refresh viewpager